# Меткозависимые похожие вопросы

Tags: предложение, вопросы, похожие-вопросы

Когда ввожу вопрос в заголовок, выскакивают 'Вопросы, которые уже могут содержать ваш ответ'. Зачастую там попадаются ответы на мой вопрос, но еще чаще там можно найти ответы на мой же вопрос, но для других языков.

После составления вопроса мы помечаем вопрос меткой. В 90% случаев в каждом вопросе имеется метка языка.

Почему бы не выводить 'Вопросы, которые уже могут содержать ваш ответ' с учетом метки языка вопроса?

Comment: Что значит "с учётом"? Выводить их перед всеми остальными? Насколько я помню, похожие вопросы отображаются ещё ДО ввода метки. А для поиска имеет смысл всё же использовать полноценный поиск, а не через схему задания вопроса и просмотра списка похожих.

Comment: @alexolut есть такое. Вобще, по идее, поле для метки должно быть между текстом и заголовком.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что не определено, что такое "метка языка вопроса". Система меток на сайте плоская, не предусмотрено их деления на различные типы. Одни метки означают язык, другие - библиотеку, третьи - вообще непонятное нечто. Если пользователь вводит метки [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[boost](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost)[файлы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b), как машина должна понять, что именно С++ - это метка языка? Единственное отличие меток языка от других, это то что к ним привязана определенная подсветка синтаксиса, но это есть не для всех языков.

В общем, нужно сначала переделать систему меток, так чтобы они делились на типы. Только тогда можно будет это провернуть.

Comment: Можно просто отображать в первую очередь вопросы, которые имею пересечения по меткам с текущим

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я раньше думал, что так и работает, но похоже метки вообще никак не учитываются. Только что попробовал вписать в заголовок "Не работает SQL запрос" и в метки c#. Первым в списке выводит вопрос по php, хотя существует вопрос с точно таким названием по c#.

Comment: похожие вопросы даже если они про другие языки всё равно могут быть полезны. Метка это всего один из многих сигналов при приоритизации поиска. Поиск это весьма специфичная функциональность -- знание, что метка это название языка легко получить (это не требует "переделать систему меток" по крайней мере для подавляющего числа вопросов), но тупо исключать вопросы, потому что они буквально языковую метку не содержат, не стоит